# A question in matrix theory, SVD related.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For four $m\times n$ matrices A, B, A', B'. If $AA^\dagger=A'A'^\dagger, BB^\dagger=B'B'^\dagger$ and $AB^\dagger=A'B'^\dagger$, then if there always exists an unitary matrix V in U(n) such that $A=A'V$, $B=B'V$? (It has been shown in the other question that $AA^\dagger=BB^\dagger$, then A=BV, for some unitary V.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure. To note this, define the $2m\times n$ matrices
$$
 \mathcal{A}=\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\end{pmatrix},\qquad \mathcal{B}=\begin{pmatrix}A'\\B'\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now 
$$
 \mathcal{A}\mathcal{A}^*=\begin{pmatrix}AA^*&AB^*\\BA^*&BB^*\end{pmatrix}=
\mathcal{B}\mathcal{B}^*
$$
by our assumptions, and so (according to the answer to the other question you mentioned) there exists a matrix $V\in U(n)$ such that $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}V$. Now write this out in components and you see that $V$ is the desired matrix.